# How to emit new asset without minimized in webpack5 custom plugin?

Tags: plugins, webpack-5

Let's say i have following custom plugin:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');


const pluginName = 'TestWebpackPlugin';

class TestWebpackPlugin {
    constructor(opts) {
        this.options = opts || {};
    }

  apply(compiler) {
      const options = this.options

    
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('TestWebpackPlugin', (compilation) => {
        compilation.hooks.needAdditionalPass.tap('TestWebpackPlugin', () => false)

        compilation.hooks.processAssets.tap(
            {
              name: 'TestWebpackPlugin',
              stage: webpack.Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_DERIVED
            },
            (assets) => {
              // this new asset will also be minimized if mode = production
              // the question is: how to make this new asset ignored by minimizer?
              compilation.emitAsset(
                'newfile',
                new webpack.sources.RawSource('console.log("test content")')
              );
            }
          );
          
    });
  }
}

module.exports = TestWebpackPlugin
```

the question is: how to make this new asset ignored by minimizer?

Answer (score 1):

I found the question while searching for more information on the `emitAsset` method (how to write in UTF-8).

I am rewriting a Webpack 4 plugin (in an Angular context) with this new syntax, following the example given at https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-plugin/, and when I write the file at the given `Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_SUMMARIZE` stage, I find out that:

1. I can give a relative path, like: `./i18n/${fileName}.json`
2. The written files are not minimized